# beginner Powershell Script Error

Tags: powershell

To load a text file of 3 ip addresses comma separated values, into an array, and then have the contents in the array changed for every 3rd octet of the ip address, and then exported back to a csv or text file.

```
##load file to an array
    $ipFileName="C:\Users\HarmanGrewal\Google Drive\win213\assignment2\IP.txt"
    $array1=@()
    $array1=Get-Content $ipFileName -Delimiter ","
#now we have the contents in an array
    $count=0
foreach($i in $array1){
                       $array1[$count] = $array1[$count] -replace "\.\d{1}\.",".2."
                       $count++
                      }
Get-Content $array1 | export-csv -path "C:\Users\HarmanGrewal\test.txt"
```

A successful exportation of data to a csv file.

An empty csv file instead.

```
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\HarmanGrewal\192.168.2.10,' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\HarmanGrewal\Google Drive\win213\assignment2\assignment2QuestionAnswer1.ps1:13 char:1
+ Get-Content $array1 | export-csv -path "C:\Users\HarmanGrewal\test.tx …
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\HarmanGrewal\192.168.2.10,:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFound  Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\HarmanGrewal\192.168.2.14,' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\HarmanGrewal\Google Drive\win213\assignment2\assignment2QuestionAnswer1.ps1:13 char:1
+ Get-Content $array1 | export-csv -path "C:\Users\HarmanGrewal\test.tx …
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\HarmanGrewal\192.168.2.14,:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFound Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Get-Content : Illegal characters in path.
At C:\Users\HarmanGrewal\Google Drive\win213\assignment2\assignment2QuestionAnswer1.ps1:13 char:1
+ Get-Content $array1 | export-csv -path "C:\Users\HarmanGrewal\test.tx …
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (C:\Users\HarmanGrewal\192.168.2.15:String) [Get-Content], ArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\HarmanGrewal\192.168.2.15' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\HarmanGrewal\Google Drive\win213\assignment2\assignment2QuestionAnswer1.ps1:13 char:1
+ Get-Content $array1 | export-csv -path "C:\Users\HarmanGrewal\test.tx …
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\HarmanGrewal\192.168.2.15:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Read the 3 IP addresses from the input file into an array.
# .TrimEnd() ensures that a trailing newline, if any, is stripped (syntax requires PSv3+)
$ips = (Get-Content $ipFileName -Delimiter ",").TrimEnd()

# Replace single-digit IP octets with fixed value 2,
# join the resulting IPs with ',' again, and write to an output file.
$ips -replace '\.\d{1}\.', '.2.' -join ',' | Set-Content "C:\Users\HarmanGrewal\test.txt"
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

```
$array1=@()
$array1 = ...
```

`$array1=@()` is pointless, because the next line assigns to `$array1` *again*, which means that *its* RHS determines the data type of `$array1`, irrespective of the previous `=@()` assignment;
if the `Get-Content` command happens to return a *single* value, `$array1` will be a *scalar*; you could prevent that by enclosing the `Get-Content` command in `@(...)`, the array-subexpression operator, but in PSv3+ that is generally not necessary, due to its unified handling of scalars and collections.

`foreach($i in $array1)` enumerates the array elements *themselves*, where `$i` is a by-value copy of each array element.
Instead of using a separate `$count` variable to access the elements by reference via their index in order to update them, PowerShell allows you to simply *recreate* the array as a whole:

```
$array1 = foreach ($el in $array1) { $el -replace "\.\d{1}\.",".2." }
```

or, more concisely, relying on the `-replace` operator's support for array-valued LHS values:

```
$array1 = $array1 -replace "\.\d{1}\.",".2."
```

As [Harsh Jaswal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47736173/45375) points out, `Get-Content $array1` mistakenly passes intended file *contents*, whereas what `Get-Content` expects are *filename* arguments to read contents from.

Since the values to output - in array `$array1` - are already in memory, you can simply send *them* through the pipeline *directly*.

`Export-Csv` operates on the *properties* of an object, and since you're supplying *string* objects that only have a `.Length` property, all that will be exported is that property, which is not the intent.

In the case at hand you have to write a *text file directly*, using `Set-Content`, based on constructing CSV-format strings in memory.
Note that `Set-Content` uses the system's legacy "ANSI" code page by default; use `-Encoding <encodingName>` to change that.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is if you are using `foreach` here then there is no need of `$count` variable. And the second thing is in your last line you are passing collection `$array1` to `Get-Content`. It takes the path as a parameter. So it is trying to get the contents of the file stored at `$array1`, which is not correct.
Please modify the code as below.

```
$ipFileName="C:\Users\HarmanGrewal\Google Drive\win213\assignment2\IP.txt"
$array1=@()
$array1=Get-Content $ipFileName -Delimiter ","
#now we have the contents in an array
foreach($i in $array1){
    $i = $i -replace "\.\d{1}\.",".2."
    $i
}
$array1 | export-csv -path C:\Users\HarmanGrewal\test.txt
```